# How to prevent PHP echo from ending a JS string?

Tags: javascript, php, javascript-injection

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sign up page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sign up page</h1>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <input placeholder="Enter your username" name="username"/><br/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" style="margin-bottom:5px" name="password"/><br/>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["username"],$_POST["password"],$_POST["submit"])){
            if(mb_strlen($_POST["username"])<8){
            ?>
            <script>
                alert("Your username must be at least 8 characters long.");
                var i=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
                i.value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>";
                i.focus();
            </script>
            <?php
            }else if(mb_strlen($_POST["password"])<8){
            ?>
            <script>
                alert("Your password must be at least 8 characters long.");
                var i=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
                i.value="<?php echo $_POST['password']; ?>";
                i.focus();
            </script>
            <?php
            }else{
                echo "Successfully signed up!";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine most of the time, but if you try entering `";f();` into the username field, you get an error in the console and no alert.

As is clearly visible, that is happening because when PHP receives the input, it echoes it in the JS string.  `";` ends the string and the statement, while `f();` causes an error which prevents the input from focusing.  This occurred under 8 characters, therefore causing it to fall under `mb_strlen($_POST["username"])<8`.

Usually I would just use `htmlspecialchars`, but if you try adding that, then if you put `";<!--`, it comes out with `&lt;` instead of `<`.  Some users may want `<` (or other `&*;` characters) in their username, and (if they weren't developers) would be surprised what `&lt;` means.

So how do I prevent the JavaScript Injection from occurring while still keeping User Friendliness?

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to use this `f()` or whatever.

Comment: @AbraCadaver : You are supposed to enter `";f();` in the username box to reproduce the javascript injection.  `f()` isn't defined so it causes an error (which shouldn't occur).  I am asking on how to fix this and prevent the JS injection.

Comment: You should try and contain the logging-in logic in the back end (including counter-checking it against user names and passwords from a database). Only the result should then be "sent" back to the front end (JavaScript), preferably by means of an AJAX.

Comment: @AbraCadaver : But when I put it back in the username box (so that they don't have to retype everything again), it shows as `&lt;` which I don't want.  It should show as `<` but not cause any JS injections.

Comment: I see, try `addslashes`

Comment: @AbraCadaver : Works perfectly!  I will accept as answer after making sure that is the best one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode) to output your values (and note you no longer need the enclosing `"`s):

```
i.value=<?php echo json_encode($_POST['username']); ?>;
```

This will ensure that quotes within the string are escaped and the entire value is treated by JavaScript as a string. For your example data, this will produce

```
"\";f();"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the double-quote in this example.  Try `addslashes`:

```
i.value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['username']); ?>";
```

Though [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) answer may be better for JS.  I'm more PHP than JS.

Comment: `json_encode` is the correct method of sending data form PHP to JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You should never inject unsanitized code into anything. This can cause XSS attacks at the least.

I think the easiest way to sanitize your code while keeping the user friendliness would be to use `json_encode()`

```
<?php
    }else if(mb_strlen($_POST["password"])<8){
$data = json_encode(['password' => $_POST['password']]);
?>

<script>
    alert("Your password must be at least 8 characters long.");
    var user_data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
    var i=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
    i.value=user_data.password;
    i.focus();
</script>
```

However!

You should really be putting this in the Input element:

```
<input type="password" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'] ?? '',ENT_QUOTES); ?>" placeholder="Enter your password" style="margin-bottom:5px" name="password"/>
```